# Adding an item to a container, but first a lot of checks

Tags: performance, algorithm, php, laravel

First time on this exchange, so giving this a title was already a challenge.
So let's start at the beginning. This kind professor [Güneş Erdoğan](https://people.bath.ac.uk/ge277/) has published an [CLP (Container Loading Problem) solver](https://people.bath.ac.uk/ge277/clp-spreadsheet-solver/). His solution is made in a spreadsheet so it is VBA for Applications.

I have manually converted his code to a PHP script. I have everything working and running. But he has stated himself that there is room for improvement.

His algorithm has a while loop where it keeps making solutions based on random sorting. If the new solution is better than the current, the current gets replaced. Since the algorithm has a given time as input, for example 30, the code will keep doing this for 30 seconds and then return the best solution.

So I took the challenge to improve the code and try to get more iterations within the 30 seconds.
Using a profiling tool it shows me that the method called `addItemToContainer` takes up most of the time. I've already spend quite some time on this method to try and improve it but I honestly can't find anything.

Then I found this exchange and I'm curious if anyone here can help me any further.

`addItemToContainer` code:

```
public function addItemToContainer(Solution $solution, int $containerIndex, int $itemTypeIndex, int $addType): bool
{
    $currentContainer = $solution->containers[$containerIndex];
    $currentItemType = $this->itemTypeList[$itemTypeIndex];
    $minX = $currentContainer->width + 1;
    $minY = $currentContainer->height + 1;
    $minZ = $currentContainer->length + 1;

    $candidatePosition = -1;

    $additionPointsCount = \count($currentContainer->addition_points);

    // Checks if the item is able to fit into the current container based on volume
    if (($currentContainer->volume_packed + $currentItemType->volume) > $currentContainer->volume_capacity) {
        goto addItemToContainerFinish;
    }

    // Checks if the item is able to fit into the current container based on weight
    if (($currentContainer->weight_packed + $currentItemType->weight) > $currentContainer->weight_capacity) {
        goto addItemToContainerFinish;
    }

    // Checks each rotation, based on the rotation order of the solution
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $rotationIndex = $i;
        if ($candidatePosition !== -1) {
            goto addItemToContainerFinish;
        }

        $currentRotation = $solution->rotation_order[$itemTypeIndex][$rotationIndex];

        // Forbidden rotations
        if ((($currentRotation === 3) || ($currentRotation === 4)) && ($currentItemType->xy_rotatable === false)) {
            continue;
        }

        if ((($currentRotation === 5) || ($currentRotation === 6)) && ($currentItemType->yz_rotatable === false)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Symmetry breaking
        if (($currentRotation === 2) && (\abs($currentItemType->width - $currentItemType->length) < $this->epsilon)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (($currentRotation === 4) && (\abs($currentItemType->width - $currentItemType->height) < $this->epsilon)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (($currentRotation === 6) && (\abs($currentItemType->height - $currentItemType->length) < $this->epsilon)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Loops through each addition point to find the next gap to put a new item
        for ($j = 0; $j < $currentContainer->addition_point_count; $j++) {
            if ($additionPointsCount - 1 >= $j) {
                $additionPoint = $currentContainer->addition_points[$j];
                $originX = $additionPoint->origin_x;
                $originY = $additionPoint->origin_y;
                $originZ = $additionPoint->origin_z;
            } else {
                $originX = 0;
                $originY = 0;
                $originZ = 0;
            }

            // set opposite positions based on the rotation which is calculated above
            switch ($currentRotation) {
                case 1:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->width;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->height;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->length;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->length;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->height;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->width;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->width;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->length;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->height;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->height;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->length;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->width;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->height;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->width;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->length;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $oppositeX = $originX + $currentItemType->length;
                    $oppositeY = $originY + $currentItemType->width;
                    $oppositeZ = $originZ + $currentItemType->height;
                    break;
                default:
                    $oppositeX = 0;
                    $oppositeY = 0;
                    $oppositeZ = 0;
                    break;
            }

            // Check the feasibility of all four corners, w.r.t. to the other items
            if (($oppositeX > $currentContainer->width + $this->epsilon) || ($oppositeY > $currentContainer->height + $this->epsilon) || ($oppositeZ > $currentContainer->length + $this->epsilon)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Check if there is conflict with other items within the container
            foreach ($currentContainer->items as $item) {
                if (
                    ($oppositeX < $item->origin_x + $this->epsilon) ||
                    ($item->opposite_x < $originX + $this->epsilon) ||
                    ($oppositeY < $item->origin_y + $this->epsilon) ||
                    ($item->opposite_y < $originY + $this->epsilon) ||
                    ($oppositeZ < $item->origin_z + $this->epsilon) ||
                    ($item->opposite_z < $originZ + $this->epsilon)
                ) {
                    // No conflict
                } else {
                    // Conflict
                    continue 2 ;
                }
            }

            // Support
            if ($originY < $this->epsilon) {
                $support = true;
            } else {
                $areaSupported = 0;
                $support = false;
                $containerItemsCount = \count($currentContainer->items);
                for ($k = $containerItemsCount - 1; $k >= 0; $k--) {
                    $item = $currentContainer->items[$k];
                    if (\abs($originY - $item->opposite_y) < $this->epsilon) {
                        // Check for intersection
                        $intersectionRight = $oppositeX;
                        if ($intersectionRight > $item->opposite_x) {
                            $intersectionRight = $item->opposite_x;
                        }

                        $intersectionLeft = $originX;
                        if ($intersectionLeft < $item->origin_x) {
                            $intersectionLeft = $item->origin_x;
                        }

                        $intersectionTop = $oppositeZ;
                        if ($intersectionTop > $item->opposite_z) {
                            $intersectionTop = $item->opposite_z;
                        }

                        $intersectionBottom = $originZ;
                        if ($intersectionBottom < $item->origin_z) {
                            $intersectionBottom = $item->origin_z;
                        }

                        if (($intersectionRight > $intersectionLeft) && ($intersectionTop > $intersectionBottom)) {
                            $areaSupported += (($intersectionRight - $intersectionLeft) * ($intersectionTop - $intersectionBottom));
                            if ($areaSupported > (($oppositeX - $originX) * ($oppositeZ - $originZ)) - $this->epsilon) {
                                $support = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!$support) {
                continue;
            }

            // No conflicts at this point
            if (
                ($originZ < $minZ) ||
                (($originZ <= $minZ + $this->epsilon) && ($originY < $minY)) ||
                (($originZ <= $minZ + $this->epsilon) && ($originY <= $minY + $this->epsilon) && ($originX < $minX))
            ) {
                $minX = $originX;
                $minY = $originY;
                $minZ = $originZ;
                $candidatePosition = $j;
                $candidateRotation = $currentRotation;
            }
        }
    }

    // Portion of the function where the item gets added to the container
    addItemToContainerFinish :

    // If the candidate position is equal to -1 return
    if ($candidatePosition === -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $newItem = new Item();
        $newItem->item_type = $itemTypeIndex;
        if ($additionPointsCount - 1 >= $candidatePosition) {
            $newItem->origin_x = $currentContainer->addition_points[$candidatePosition]->origin_x;
            $newItem->origin_y = $currentContainer->addition_points[$candidatePosition]->origin_y;
            $newItem->origin_z = $currentContainer->addition_points[$candidatePosition]->origin_z;
        } else {
            $newItem->origin_x = 0;
            $newItem->origin_y = 0;
            $newItem->origin_z = 0;
        }
        $newItem->rotation = $candidateRotation;
        $newItem->mandatory = $currentItemType->mandatory;

        // Based on the resulted rotation set the opposite position
        switch ($candidateRotation) {
            case 1:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->width;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->height;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->length;
                break;
            case 2:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->length;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->height;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->width;
                break;
            case 3:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->width;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->length;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->height;
                break;
            case 4:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->height;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->length;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->width;
                break;
            case 5:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->height;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->width;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->length;
                break;
            case 6:
                $newItem->opposite_x = $newItem->origin_x + $currentItemType->length;
                $newItem->opposite_y = $newItem->origin_y + $currentItemType->width;
                $newItem->opposite_z = $newItem->origin_z + $currentItemType->height;
                break;
        }

        \array_push($solution->containers[$containerIndex]->items, $newItem);

        // Update the volume and weight of the container
        $currentContainer->volume_packed += $currentItemType->volume;
        $currentContainer->weight_packed += $currentItemType->weight;

        if ($addType === 2) {
            $currentContainer->repack_item_count[$itemTypeIndex] = $currentContainer->repack_item_count[$itemTypeIndex] - 1;
        }

        // Update the addition points
        for ($i = $candidatePosition; $i < $currentContainer->addition_point_count - 1; $i++) {
            $currentContainer->addition_points[$i] = clone($currentContainer->addition_points[$i + 1]);
        }

        $currentContainer->addition_point_count = $currentContainer->addition_point_count - 1;

        $itemsCount = \count($currentContainer->items);
        $lastItem = $currentContainer->items[$itemsCount - 1];
        // Add a new addition point to the container based on the last item
        if (($lastItem->opposite_x < $currentContainer->width - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->origin_y < $currentContainer->height - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->origin_z < $currentContainer->length - $this->epsilon)) {
            $currentContainer->addition_point_count = $currentContainer->addition_point_count + 1;
            $additionPoint = new ItemLocation();
            $additionPoint->origin_x = $lastItem->opposite_x;
            $additionPoint->origin_y = $lastItem->origin_y;
            $additionPoint->origin_z = $lastItem->origin_z;
            if (\count($currentContainer->addition_points) < $currentContainer->addition_point_count) {
                \array_push($currentContainer->addition_points, $additionPoint);
            } else {
                $currentContainer->addition_points[$currentContainer->addition_point_count - 1] = $additionPoint;
            }
        }

        // Add a new addition point to the container based on the last item
        if (($lastItem->origin_x < $currentContainer->width - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->opposite_y < $currentContainer->height - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->origin_z < $currentContainer->length - $this->epsilon)) {
            $currentContainer->addition_point_count = $currentContainer->addition_point_count + 1;
            $additionPoint = new ItemLocation();
            $additionPoint->origin_x = $lastItem->origin_x;
            $additionPoint->origin_y = $lastItem->opposite_y;
            $additionPoint->origin_z = $lastItem->origin_z;
            if (\count($currentContainer->addition_points) < $currentContainer->addition_point_count) {
                \array_push($currentContainer->addition_points, $additionPoint);
            } else {
                $currentContainer->addition_points[$currentContainer->addition_point_count - 1] = $additionPoint;
            }
        }

        // Add a new addition point to the container based on the last item
        if (($lastItem->origin_x < $currentContainer->width - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->origin_y < $currentContainer->height - $this->epsilon) &&
            ($lastItem->opposite_z < $currentContainer->length - $this->epsilon)) {
            $currentContainer->addition_point_count = $currentContainer->addition_point_count + 1;
            $additionPoint = new ItemLocation();
            $additionPoint->origin_x = $lastItem->origin_x;
            $additionPoint->origin_y = $lastItem->origin_y;
            $additionPoint->origin_z = $lastItem->opposite_z;
            if (\count($currentContainer->addition_points) < $currentContainer->addition_point_count) {
                \array_push($currentContainer->addition_points, $additionPoint);
            } else {
                $currentContainer->addition_points[$currentContainer->addition_point_count - 1] = $additionPoint;
            }
        }

        // Update the profit
        if ($itemsCount === 1) {
            $solution->net_profit += ($currentItemType->profit - $solution->containers[$containerIndex]->cost);
        } else {
            $solution->net_profit += $currentItemType->profit;
        }

        // Update the volume per container and the total volume
        $solution->total_volume += $currentItemType->volume;
        $solution->total_weight += $currentItemType->weight;

        // Update the unpacked items
        if ($addType === 1) {
            $solution->unpacked_item_count[$itemTypeIndex] = $solution->unpacked_item_count[$itemTypeIndex] - 1;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

So the main question is if maybe you can find something which possibly can improve the amount of iterations the algorithm can do.

[(Since the code is pretty big, here is a pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/wC2XBFY6)

Comment: (`giving this a title [is] already a challenge` that's the spirit!)(Sounds like [simulated annealing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) might be a better strategy.)

Comment: Wow, I've only ever read about the mythological creature `goto` in the php docs... I've never actually seen it in the wild!

Comment: @mickmackusa haha yea, I can't think of the last time I've used it. But it seemed like the perfect fit!

Comment: following `No conflicts at this point`, the condition `(($originZ <= $minZ + $this->epsilon) && ($originY < $minY))` is redundant (included in the last one).

Comment: The coding of orientation independence (rotation) sucks (led to longish code with parts repeated with dimensions permuted), probably due to *naming* dimensions instead of enumeration/array usage.

Comment: @greybeard In the last condition, if `(($originZ <= $minZ + $this->epsilon) && ($originY < $minY))` is true. The if statement doesn't return true when the last part (`($originX < $minX)`) is false. So it's not redundant I would say.. I can agree with your other comment, but using enumeration/array I would still have to use a switch for the rotation, so the longish code will always remain. That's how I look at it.

Comment: At the condition's top level, three (parenthesised) expressions are combined with *logical or*: I expect the last one to be true whenever the second one is.

Comment: @greybeard, Okay. Why isn't the first one redundant since it is included the exact same way in the third one?

Comment: Never said it wasn't. That part does *not* impose any relation between `$originY` and `$minY`. To be explicit: while the algorithm isn't yours, the PHP implementation presented is?

Comment: @greybeard Correct, had to write it all in PHP myself. After that I thought I should be able to change things up since VBA is ofcourse different then  PHP. And the professor stated that there is 'clearly' room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't personally know of any advantage to prefixing php functions with a backslash, so consider removing the unnecessary character.  (or tell me why it is useful)
2. Perform arithmetic once.  AKA "Don't Repeat Yourself" (**D.R.Y.**)

   ```
   $additionPointsCount = \count($currentContainer->addition_points);
   ```

   becomes:

   ```
   $lastPoint = count($currentContainer->addition_points) - 1;
   ```
3. I'd have to double check the docs to recommend a replacement for `goto()`, but I'm pretty sure that the php docs say to avoid it all costs.  I recall a comic strip illustration that conveys the importance of its avoidance.  Then again, unless I am overlooking something, perhaps this is a suitable use case which avoids having to manually transfer variables into a new curom function scope.
4. If two separate sets if conditions lead to the same `goto`, then write D.R.Y. code and merge the conditions.  Likewise with several conditions that lead to `continue`.
5. To simplify conditions evaluating the same value with two or more sets of `||`, use `in_array()`. When ordering the conditions, write the least expensive evaluations first and the most taxing evaluations (that, say, make a function call) last.  Because conditions short circuit on the first "condition breaking" false, the heavier checks are avoided and efficiency is gained.  Also, try to remove excessive parentheses.

   ```
   if ((($currentRotation === 3) || ($currentRotation === 4)) && ($currentItemType->xy_rotatable === false)) {
       continue;
   }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   if ($currentItemType->xy_rotatable === false && in_array($currentRotation, [3, 4])) {
       continue;
   }
   ```
6. If you can't manage to reverse all of the logic in a multi-conditional expression (leading to `continue 2;`), then wrap all of the conditions in parentheses and write `!` before it to provide the opposite boolean evaluation, this way you don't need the `else` branch.
7. When pushing just one element into an indexed array, just use square braced syntax and spare the `array_push()` call.